# Enable/Disable <p:commandButton> in footer of <p:dataTable> based on change of <p:column selection="multiple">

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I have a datatable where I am showing List of Employees. At the end of the datatable I have a commandbutton. Now if user selects any checkbox inside the datatable, I want my commandbutton to be enabled. Initially the command button is disabled.

Below is my index.xhtml page

```
<p:dataTable value="#{userPreferencesBean.studentDataModel}"
                var="studentDetails" emptyMessage="No Student found."
                selection="#{userPreferencesBean.selectedStudents}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    List of Students
                </f:facet>

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="submit" listener="#{userPreferencesBean.onRowSelect}"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="submit" listener="#{userPreferencesBean.onRowSelect}"/>

                <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%" />

                //All the columns 

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Save Preferences"
                        icon="ui-icon-disk" style="float:right;"
                        action="#{userPreferencesBean.savePreferredInterfaces}"
                        update=":#{p:component('selectedInterfaceDetails')}" 
                        disabled="#{not userPreferencesBean.hasPreferenceChanged eq false}"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Below is my backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserPreferencesBean implements Serializable {

    private boolean hasPreferenceChanged = false;

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        this.setHasPreferenceChanged(true);
    }

    public boolean isHasPreferenceChanged() {
        return hasPreferenceChanged;
    }

    public void setHasPreferenceChanged(boolean hasPreferenceChanged) {
        this.hasPreferenceChanged = hasPreferenceChanged;
    }
```

What I am expecting is that once I select a row, my submit button should be enabled. But it is not happening. Could you please help me to understand where I am doing wrong? Thanks.

With regards,
Sudipta Deb

Comment: any updates on this? i am trying to achieve the exact same behavior... Tried to change bean scope to view with no luck!

Answer (score -1):

Try put your table into form.

Also you can make it more convient:

```
<p:commandButton id="submit" ... disabled="#{userPreferencesBean.selectedStudents==null}"/>
```

Comment: It is already inside the form. My userPreferencesBean.selectedStudents will contain selected students saved in Database.

Comment: Sorry. I missed word 'checkbox'. I thought you want enable button on row selected. Check please if your method called.